# Extra space in echo output (error)

Tags: php, html

I want to echo out "First Name" put that is not possible i get this:

[image].

I dont know how to get a space between there and not get a error. I can give more code if that is necessary.

```
Notice: Undefined index: First Name in E:\wamp\www\classes\Validate.php on line 14
```

join.php (http://pastebin.com/Ru596655)
validate.php (http://pastebin.com/PbAG8dMK)

Comment: Please post the error here, instead of a link to an image that states the error.

Comment: Do you have any more PHP than that?

Comment: Very little info to work with, can you post your validate code

Comment: added all the code @andychukse

Comment: Close the space in name of your input box First Name, use firstname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because of the space in the name of your textbox

```
<div class="join input-group">
        <a class="join_topic">First Name *</a>
        <input type="text" name="First Name" id="First Name" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('First Name')); ?>" class="form-control">
```

Instead of "First Name" use firstname

Comment: Is it not possible to get the space without having a error?

Comment: Am afraid not, space cannot be accepted, you can use underscore to connect it. Why do you need the space?

Comment: Looks better when im echoing it :P

Comment: while echoing you can use $error= str_replace("_", " ", $error); echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>$error</div>";